# Css Animation with Hover - Why does it reset to initial settings after first iteration?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm updating my portfolio site at http://jcdevelopmentsite.com/jcwebandgraphic/index.html#services. I'm creating a CSS animation hover effect on the Font Awesome icons. The transition works well, but once it finishes, it resets to the pre-hover settings. I'd like it to hold the background-color for the duration of the hover. Is this possible with pure CSS?

HTML

```
    <section id='services-section'>
        <h2 class='highlight'>Services</h2>
        <div class='main-content'>
            <div class='services'>
                <a href='#pricing-section'>
                    <i class='fa fa-laptop fa-4x'></i>
                    <h5>Static & Fluid Layouts</h5>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class='services'>
                <a href='#pricing-section'>
                    <i class='fa fa-mobile fa-4x'></i>
                    <h5>Responsive Layouts</h5>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class='services'>
                <a href='#pricing-section'>
                    <i class='fa fa-shopping-cart fa-4x'></i>
                    <h5>E-Commerce Solutions</h5>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class='services'>
                <a href='#pricing-section'>
                    <i class='fa fa-pencil-square fa-4x'></i>
                    <h5>Theme Customizations</h5>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- Closes .main-content -->
    </section>
```

CSS

```
@keyframes animate {
    from {}
    to { background-color: #332D29; }
    }
        .services:hover {
            animation-name: animate;
            animation-duration: 1s;
            animation-iteration-count: 1;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;  
            outline: 1px solid #ffffff;
            }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the default behavior for animations.

You just need to add this property:

```
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

On a side note, for this case it might be to use CSS3 transitions:

```
.services{
    transition: background-color 1s ease-in-out;
}

.services:hover{
    background-color: #332D29;
    outline: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: Thank you - I'll try that solution now. IN the meantime, can you explain to me why it would be useful in this case to use the CSS transition property? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @user2287917 I'm sure you're gonna love this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NbUYPckAE64)
When you specify a transition you just specify the property that you want to be animated. And then as soon as you change it, it'll be animated

Comment: I just skipped through that video - It seems really helpful, and I'll definitely watch it more thoroughly when I get the chance. I'm still struggling with newbie issues, so it's nice to be able to find great tutorials like this. Best wishes :)

Comment: great! first 30 minutes are for beginners :D enjoy

Comment: I will - one more thing though, if you don't mind. The transitions work beautifully, but if the mouse moves off the element before the transition-in is completed, it does not animate the transition-out. Any adivce on making it run a smooth transition, even before the animation has completed?

Comment: I didn't get what you mean.. maybe it's better to ask a new question with full a jsfiddle and then send me the link

Comment: Let me try to explain again - If the cursor moves off the element before the hover animation is completed, it does not initiate transition: background-color 1s ease-in-out;

Comment: You mean it doesn't animate the "leaving"  effect? Only the entrance?

Comment: Yes. If it does not finish the entrance animation, it does not perform the leaving animation. It just switches to the initial settings. If it does finish the entrance animation, it completes the leaving animation perfectly. I have it timed for a 1 second transition.

Comment: Ok. I haven't used it before, but I'll put one together and post it here by tomorrow morning. Thank you.

Comment: I fixed your code: https://jsfiddle.net/j2swxLgo/3/
You don't need the animation keyframes when using transitions, you just have to update the property on hover and that's it!